# Relayout of Text field that is being editted scrambles text in simulator

Tags: codenameone

I want the user to enter an artbitrary number of keywords (or keyphrases). To this end, I have a row of TextFields, one for each keyword. I add a new TextField to the row when all existing ones have text in them, so the user can enter another keyword.

The addition of a new TextField happens when a character is added to the last empty TextField; i.e. that TextField is being editted when a new TextField is added. Furthermore, the existing TextFields will be moved and resized when adding a new TextField (to make space).

This works fine on Android, but in the simulator it does not. In the similator, the TextField being editted is being moved, but the text being editted is not.

The issue can be replicated using the form below.

Kind regards, Frans.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.codename1.ui.Container;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.TextArea;
import com.codename1.ui.TextField;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.GridLayout;

public class TextFieldRelayoutForm extends Form
{
    public TextFieldRelayoutForm()
    {
        super("TextField relayout", BoxLayout.y());
        add(new Label("Type into the last text field below"));
        Strings strings = new Strings("blabla");
        strings.setStrings(Arrays.asList("one", "two"));
        add(strings);
    }

    public class Strings extends Container
    {
        private final String hint;
        private final Runnable listener;

        public Strings(String hint)
        {
            this(hint, null);
        }

        public Strings(String hint, Runnable listener)
        {
            //TextField.setUseNativeTextInput(false);
            this.hint = hint;
            this.listener = listener;
            addEmptyField();
        }

        public void setStrings(List<String> strings)
        {
            removeAll();
            for (String string : strings)
            {
                addComponent(getTextField(string));
            }
            addEmptyField();
        }

        private TextField getTextField(String text)
        {
            TextField field = new TextField("", hint, 20, TextArea.ANY);
            field.setText(text);
            field.addDataChangedListener((t,i) -> textFieldDataChanged(field));
            return field;
        }

        private void textFieldDataChanged(TextField field)
        {
            if (!hasEmptyField())
            {
                addEmptyField();
            }
            if (listener != null)
            {
                listener.run();
            }
        }

        private boolean hasEmptyField()
        {
            for (int i = getComponentCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                String string = ((TextField)getComponentAt(i)).getText();
                if (string.length() == 0)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        private void addEmptyField()
        {
            addComponent(getTextField(""));
            setLayout(new GridLayout(getComponentCount()));
            revalidate();
        }

        public List<String> getStrings()
        {
            List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < getComponentCount(); i++)
            {
                String string = ((TextField)getComponentAt(i)).getText();
                if (string.length() != 0)
                {
                    strings.add(string);
                }
            }
            return strings;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing happens in native code so when you edit we "seamlessly" layout a native text field on top of the lightweight text field and let you edit. I quoted seamlessly as this abstraction leaks on some cases and this is one of them. That's why it's a best practice to use stopEdit/startEditAsync when changing layouts or text field information.

You can read about similar issues in this post https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-stop-editing.html

Another possibly better alternative would be to use the action listener. This happens only when editing finished. This means fewer events and when you make changes you won't need to hack. The downside is that a user will need to abandon editing so the new field appears.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code to: `field.stopEditing(() -> { addEmptyField(); field.startEditing(); });` and this works both on Android and in the simulator. Unfortunately, it has the side effect of switching off and on the virtual keyboard, which is awkward since the user doesn't expect is in the middle of his typing. Since my original code seemed to be working fine on Android, I am not yet sure whether to keep the stopEditing or not.

Comment: I already tried the action listener approach, but also noted the downside you mentioned and then decided against using it, since it would not be natural for the user.

Comment: I'm not sure we can take that much further in terms of UX without going deep into platform differences. Input is **really** different between Android/iOS and making it act seamless is pretty hard. Its a common source of bugs in native apps.

Comment: I understand. I decided to use stopEditing on platforms with issues (such as the simulator) and not on other platforms (such as Android). This works fine for me.