# Text scrambled in TextField on Android when using setUseNativeTextInput(false);

Tags: android, codenameone

When using 'TextField.setUseNativeTextInput(false)', the text in TextFields is scramled while editting. It looks like there are two texts placed on top of each other: the original text and the text being editted.

This issue occurs on Android, but not in the simulator. In the simulator it allso seems like two texts are placed on top of each other (slightly displaced), but both are being editted.

The issue can be replicated with the form below.

Kind Regards, Frans

```
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.TextArea;
import com.codename1.ui.TextField;
import com.codename1.ui.layouts.BoxLayout;

public class TextFieldWithTextForm extends Form
{
    public TextFieldWithTextForm()
    {
        super("TextField with text", BoxLayout.y());
        TextField.setUseNativeTextInput(false);
        add(new Label("Remove the 4 and the k from the fields below"));
        TextField one = new TextField("", "This field one", 20, TextArea.ANY);
        one.setText("0123456789");
        add(one);
        TextField two = new TextField("", "This field two", 20, TextArea.ANY);
        two.setText("abcedfghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
        add(two);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why invoke `setUseNativeTextInput(false)`?

Comment: I was trying to find a workaround for another issue (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53593553/relayout-of-text-field-that-is-being-editted-scrambles-text-in-simulator), but it didn't solve that issue and just created an extra issue. So I removed the call from my code, but just wanted to let you know the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We deprecated this call now, it should have been deprecated before as it dates back to no longer supported implementations.

Comment: Thanks, I won't use it again :-)